# TYPO3/Extbase - How to trim values before validation/saving objects?

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

In Extbase usually I handle form validation myself within the controller, especially when I need advanced scenarios, but now I've simple, but large form with many fields, so I decided not to waste time and just use TYPO3's validators. So far so good in general it works, anyway I cannot force Extbase to trim values before validation and in result Extbase saves lot of spaces... so it's invalid, sample:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @validate StringLength(minimum=2, maximum=255)
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $fooName = '';
```

As I said I've tens of fields and would love to avoid manual validating it... is there any solution?

Note: I tried [`extbase_filter`](https://github.com/AOEpeople/extbase_filter) ext, which would be great solution if it worked (unfortunately doesn't take any effect at TYPO3 ver.: 6.2.6.

Also for obvious reasons using JS for trimming values before form send isn't a solution too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do *trim-ing* inside your `set*` methods. Validation in Extabase's MVC process happens **after** *set-ers* invoked.

So, your example would be:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @validate StringLength(minimum=2, maximum=255)
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $fooName = '';

public function setFooName($fooName)
{
    $this->fooName = trim($fooName);
}
```

Comment: That's right, I just discovered it after some debugging ;) It ensures that validation will be correct (finally!) anyway still doesn't trim values which are displayed in reloaded form (even with `trim()` added to getters as well).

Comment: This can be tricky, but you may play around in Controller with `$this->request->getReferringRequest()->getArgument('your_argument_name')`, which shouldn't be empty in case of validation error. As I understand, values form there are used as values for from fields to restore user input.

Comment: Yes, that I usually do with small forms... anyway while BE validation works now properly with this trimming in setters, then for _cosmetic_ trimming in form I'll use JS (similar like in BE TCE forms) so actually this topic is resolved for me now.